# AS3: is it required to call BitmapData.dispose()?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, garbage-collection, bitmapdata

Is it required to call BitmapData.dispose() for every BitmapData that one wants to have removed from memory completely, or does that buffer get freed anyway as soon as the BitmapData object gets garbage collected?

Answer (score 8):

Ultimately `BitmapData` will be disposed by garbage collection.

Calling `BitmapData.dispose()` frees memory immediately, which can improve performance especially in heavy use of bitmap data within frame-based animation.  Bitmap data can consume a significant amount of memory quickly.

[BitmapData, from the ActionScript 3.0 Reference for the Adobe Flash Platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#dispose%28%29)

> BitmapData.dispose() releases the memory occupied by the actual bitmap
>   data, immediately (a bitmap can consume up to 64 MB of memory). After
>   using BitmapData.dispose(), the BitmapData object is no longer usable
>   and the Flash runtime throws an exception if you call functions on the
>   BitmapData object. However, BitmapData.dispose() does not garbage
>   collect the BitmapData object (approximately 128 bytes); the memory
>   occupied by the actual BitmapData object is released at the time the
>   BitmapData object is collected by the garbage collector.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I call dispose() like this: `bitlayer.bitmapData.dispose(); bitlayer.bitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true, 0);` many times, flash memory grows quickly. Instead if I set null: `bitlayer.bitmapData = null; bitlayer.bitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true, 0);` flash memory not grows at all. I think `dispose()` have a bug.